# How to change release variant to debug variant?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded the Shuttle Music Player from GitHub and stuck with this problem while syncing project with Gradle. How can I fix this problem??

//This is the Module Gradle

```
import dependencies.Dependencies

apply plugin: Dependencies.BuildPlugins.androidLibrary

android {
    compileSdkVersion Dependencies.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Dependencies.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion Dependencies.targetSdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation Dependencies.Google.appcompat
}
```

//This the App Gradle

```
import dependencies.Dependencies

apply plugin: Dependencies.BuildPlugins.androidLibrary

android {
    compileSdkVersion Dependencies.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Dependencies.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion Dependencies.targetSdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation Dependencies.Google.appcompat
}
```

> WARNING: Module 'navigation' has variant 'debug' selected, but the
>   module ''app'' depends on variant 'release' Select 'navigation' in
>   "Build Variants" window Fix problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your android studio there is a tab build variant (usually on the left side of files view), there you will see what the variant of each dependency is selected. Try changing it to see if 'navigation' has release variant or not. 
Also your app is missing debug variant in buildTypes which is causing app to use release variant.
Try adding debug variant to your app as well then check if it build with debug or not.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I change the variant types of app to devDebug and it works

Comment: Welcome, upvote and mark correct if it helped you solving your issue.